# byte[] to photo (Northwind database) JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, photo, northwind

I'm having troubles with a photo from a given database (http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees)

An employee has a photo (and a photopath) but I don't know what to do with it.. It is a very long file.

```
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
```

Comment: is it stored as a Blob type in the database ?

Comment: Might be a base64 encoded version of some image format.

Comment: It almost seems as if you dumped 28K bytes into your "question", then didn't even bother to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: this is the xml link (view via postman) http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees?$filter=EmployeeID eq 1
An employee has a photo & a photopath... I want to retrieve (and show) the photo on a pane.. but i don't know how to.. (i'm a student first year java/second year programming)